# Abstract title space

Tags: spacing, abstract

How to diminish the space between text and abstract title?
I'm using `\usepackage{abstract} \usepackage{titlesec}` packages and have such styles for header spacing and abstract font size:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{*2}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{*2}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{\parindent}{*2}{*1}
```

I need set the height the same as above.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\defaulthyphenchar=127 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont\bfseries} 
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{*2}{*1} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{*2}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{\parindent}{*2}{*1}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    \normalsize
    \lipsum
\end{abstract}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Sub}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{SubSub}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This space is governed by the length `\abstitleskip` if you don't use the `runin` package option. Adjust it in your preamble to suit your needs, for example

```
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-20pt}
```

will bring the title and text closer.